# Express4 + Socket.io 0.9: different clients get the same non broadcast message

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

This is a web site using authentication via passport.js.

Two different users connect from different browsers and they request info about their username. The server gets the information and send them back using socket.io.

Everything works like a charm but if the two clients load the page at the same time, the information of one of them goes to both browsers, looks like the server is writing on the same socket.

Server Side:

server.js:

```
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();
var http     = require('http').createServer(app).listen(8000),
io           = require('socket.io').listen(http);
```

socket.js:

```
module.exports = function(app, io) {
  ...
  io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) { 
    ...
    //Build the information about the user and send it back
    var userData = userInfo();
    socket.emit('userInfo', userData);
    ...
   }
}
```

Client side (javascript file included in index.ejs):

```
var socket = io.connect('http://URL:8000');
...
socket.emit("all", {data}); //Hi, I need information about me.
... 
socket.on('userInfo', function (data) {
        // do some stuff...
});
```

Server debug in console gets info about the two sockets:

```
       debug - client authorized
       info  - handshake authorized Cq71N34XLyAJBTIbHCZQ
       debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/Cq71N34XLyAJBTIbHCZQ
       debug - set heartbeat interval for client Cq71N34XLyAJBTIbHCZQ
       debug - client authorized for 
       debug - websocket writing 1::
...
       debug - client authorized
       info  - handshake authorized UF6lOwOFzgjrWY54HCZP
       debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/UF6lOwOFzgjrWY54HCZP
       debug - set heartbeat interval for client UF6lOwOFzgjrWY54HCZP
       debug - client authorized for 
       debug - websocket writing 1::
```

I´ve been rewriting different parts of the app but I can´t get why the server answers same info to different sockets.